# MySQL Basics: query execution and case sensitive

Tags: mysql, sql, execution-time

I am a newbie to mysql and having some questions on it,

1. Is there any way to find the execution time of any SQL statement in 'ms' approximation using command prompt (any setting to be done pls specify).
2. how to make your mysql to allow the case sensitive property (I have to create tables with caps on but after i created, it show the name only in small letters).

Comment: For #2, you want to research "collation" - there are numerous questions about it already on SO.

Comment: Is there any way to find the execution time of any SQL statement in 'ms' approximation using command prompt (any setting to be done pls specify)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**EXPLAIN**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) statements to check the execution times.

You can use [**lower_case_table_names**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) system variable. Use lower_case_table_names=0 on Unix and lower_case_table_names=2 on Windows. However, if you use these settings, make sure you always use the correct case in all your MySQL queries and it can cause issues if you are switching systems from UNIX to WINDOWS or vice versa.

For 2ns you can also check **collation**. Some details can be found here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Check the documentation for more details.

Comment: EXPLAIN gives insight, but times are not definitive.  It depends on data, server load, table statistics and indexing.  And that doesn't include time over the network...